# Install Ruby, Rails, Gems, Passenger for 1.8.7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ruby

I am trying to move a Ruby site to a new host that's running Ubuntu 14.04, but it needs Ruby 1.8.7.  I can use rvm to install 1.8.7, but I'm unsure of how to get rails, gems, and passenger working for this version as well.

What do I need to run to set up rails, gems, and passenger for ruby 1.8.7 on my new Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score -1):

You should check gems versions that match the Ruby version.

Example:

https://rubygems.org/gems/passenger

That "Ruby Dependency >= 0" It means it will work on any version.

Another example:

Rake gem 10.2.1 depends of Ruby >= 1.9: https://rubygems.org/gems/rake/versions/10.2.1

But click on another version like this: https://rubygems.org/gems/rake/versions/10.2.2 and it says ">= 1.8.7" and it should work in your case.

So, you need to manually check for the right version of each gem.

Comment: This doesn't tell me what I asked.  All you said was to check the version.  I understand I don't have the right versions.  What are the steps I need to perform to get the right versions for Ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: I explained, you need to manually check at rubygems site the right versions. Like I did in the examples.